# App rejected by PlayStore for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

we developed school app with flutter but android didn't accept it.  There is a homework upload module in the application, where the student selects a file and uploads it to the server.  Google play did not accept this, we have removed this feature for now and sent it.  How can we solve this on flutter as below feedbacks.

We used file picker package https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

> Apps should only request access to device storage which is critical for the app to function, and may not request access to device storage on behalf of any third-party for any purpose that is unrelated to critical user-facing app functionality.
> Android devices running Android "R" (Android 11) or later, will require the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in order to manage access in shared storage. All apps that target R or later and request broad access to shared storage ("All files access") must successfully pass an appropriate access review prior to publishing. Apps allowed to use this permission must clearly prompt users to enable "All files access" for their app under "Special app access" settings. For more information on the R requirements, please see this help article

Comment: `a homework upload module in the application, where the student selects a file and uploads it to the server. Google play did not accept this` Well we do not believe that. As selecting files and uploading is very ok. Please post the real problem.

Comment: Requesting read AND write access to entire storage of user is bad (and in most cases lazy) design that was deprecated and google will actively deny apps that do it just because they need to pick a handful of files.

Comment: @blackapps I'm not talking about an unreal problem.  Here is the image of the assignment upload page. https://www.hizliresim.com/qnjwpny

Comment: You did not show the real reason that caused your problem. It seems you dont realise what you have to change.

Answer (score 0):

For android 11 and newer you should use action_createdocument and action_open_document. see at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#use-cases details. But in this case it will be not so easy to you get file name.